# Android Accessing Child TextViews from Gridlayout

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-gridlayout

Currently I have a Gridlayout that consist of NxN number of TextViews.

I have been trying to access individual textview objects inside the grid, using onclick, but it's not working.

Below is a snippet of my code

```
TextView tv;
final GridLayout gv = (GridLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.map_grid);


gv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            tv = (TextView)gv.getFocusedChild();//gives me a null object
            System.out.println(tv.getId());//error 

        }
    });
```

Is it because getFocusedChild doesn't work this way?

Also my xml for my gridView

```
     <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_grid"
        android:layout_width="800px"
        android:layout_height="600px"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:columnCount="20"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:rowCount="15"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="30dp" >

    </GridLayout>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
gv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
  TextView  textview = (TextView) view;
            position = i;
                if(position != 0){
                    textview.setText("Hi");
}}});
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work, I'm still trying to search for a way to access the children textviews

Comment: its work on my application i can share with you my code

Comment: I found a workaround by setting onclicklistener for each of the child textview and then do the action within it instead of accessing thru gridlayout onclick. it seems to be working now

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setOnItemClickListener instead setOnClickListener

```
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

      // write your code
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, seOnItemClickListener cannot be resolved, do you know what is the problem? Current I have place this under onCreate()